# Elastic Beanstalk's nginx configuration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have added nginx test.conf files in side .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/test.conf following this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html)

I have confirmed that files are copied from logs. I have followed everything correctly still files are not added.

```
# Node.js version: 8.11.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.5.0
# eb activity logs from my instance
creating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/
inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/https-instance.config
creating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/nginx/
creating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/
inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/test.conf
```

> Update as of 5th Sep 2018

```
# Some configuration of nginx can be by placing files in /etc/nginx/conf.d
# using Configuration Files.
# http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html 
# 
# Modifications of nginx.conf can be performed using container_commands to modify 
  the staged version located in /tmp/deployment/config/etc#nginx#nginx.conf

# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RaúlFerràs Not yet, for now if i have some changes to my nginx.conf file, i am doing it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Node.js container you should read this document instead:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

The one you linked is for Java container ;)

Comment: Oops ! Can you help me with any link on how to override the main nginx.conf as i have to add stream support to nginx

Comment: The link I posted explains you how to overwrite it. If you are specifically asking how to add stream support, then sorry I have no idea.

Comment: The link explains to overwrite files under the conf.d files, but not main nginx conf files, and adding files under conf.d folder also work for node js, but can't overwrite nginx.conf.